# Numpy Conditionally Replace Column Elements

Tags: python, numpy

So I already took a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751455/conditional-replace-within-a-column-of-a-numpy-array).

I know you can conditionally replace a single column, but what about multiple columns? When I tried it, it doesn't seem to work.

```
the_data = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
                     [0, 1, 3, 1],
                     [3, 4, 1, 3],
                     [0, 1, 2, 0],
                     [2, 1, 0, 0]])

the_data[:,0][the_data[:,0] == 0] = -1 # this works

columns_to_replace = [0, 1, 3]
the_data[:,columns_to_replace][the_data[:,columns_to_replace] == 0] = -1 # this does not work
```

I initially thought that the second case doesn't work because I thought `the_data[:,columns_to_replace]` creates a copy instead of directly referencing the elements. However, if that were the case, then the first case shouldn't work either, when you are only replacing the single column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're indeed getting a copy because you're using *advanced indexing*:

> Advanced indexing is triggered when the selection object, obj, is a *non-tuple sequence object*, an ndarray (of data type integer or bool), or a tuple with at least one sequence object or ndarray (of data type integer or bool). There are two types of advanced indexing: integer and Boolean.
>
> **Advanced indexing always returns a copy of the data** (contrast with basic slicing that returns a view).

(Taken from [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html))

The first part works because it uses basic slicing.

---

I think you can do this without copying, but still with some memory overhead:

```
columns_to_replace = [0, 1, 3]

mask = np.zeros(the_data.shape, bool) # don't use too much memory
mask[:, columns_to_replace] = 1

np.place(the_data, (the_data == 0) * mask, [-1]) # this doesn't copy anything
```

Comment: Is there a workaround to this that doesn't invoke a copy? Or is looping the only option?

Comment: @user3426943, looks like there is a workaround. Please see my edit.

Comment: @user3483203, it still allocates memory, it just doesn't initialize it (and you'll have to fill it in anyway, with ones and zeros).

Comment: `the_data[(the_data==0)*mask]=-1` should also work.  The key is to find a `mask` that combines the columns criteria and the 0's test, as you do with the boolean `*`.

Comment: @hpaulj, and it does work, indeed, and it also looks simpler. I was searching for a solution that would _very clearly_ say: "I'm not creating a copy instead of a view", so my solution's a bit too verbose about that.

Comment: Due to broadcasting `mask` can start as 1d, `mask = np.zeros(the_data.shape[1], bool); mask[cols_to_replace] = True`.  Then combine it the zeros with: `mask & (the_data==0)`.

Comment: @ForceBru is just using a for loop another valid method? It seems much more readable and intuitive to understand.

Comment: @user3426943, yeah, but NumPy's vectorized code may be orders of magnitude faster than plain Python loops. Of course, if you find loops that much more readable and/or your tests don't find significant speed-ups with pure NumPy code, you can very well use loops.